# Replaced Main.storyboard, broke the wiring somehow

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

Help! I was a few days into a project which I stupidly started as Objective C, then realized "I'm a web developer, obviously I should switch to Swift now that it exists!", so I created a new Swift project from the same Xcode template (Master-Detail Application), copied in my Main.storyboard and .xcdatamodeld, and then started porting all the code I had written to swift. One day in and I'm ready to test my ported code...

But the application crashes here:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as UINavigationController
>>  let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as MasterViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    return true
}
```

---

### Edit

And the debug console says:

```
2014-12-13 14:45:28.323 Rings[12765:760712] Unknown class MasterViewController in Interface Builder file.
2014-12-13 14:45:28.332 Rings[12765:760712] Unknown class DetailViewController in Interface Builder file.
Printing description of *(masterNavigationController._navigationBar):
```

(UINavigationBar) [0] = {}

...but those two classes do at least exist--I guess this is where the disconnect is?

---

I figured if I made sure all the IBOutlets and IBActions in my code were named and typed the same (they are) that the old Main.storyboard would run fine in the new project....but it seems something is disconnected between the storyboard IB objects and the AppDelegate's view controller setup code. I'm not even sure where to look. Can anyone tip me off where to start looking?

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?

Comment: @PhillipMills I get an EXC_BREAKPOINT in assembly code, the `>>` line is one step up in the call stack. If I skip past it, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Xcode has highlighted the next line, but that line hasn't executed)

Comment: Anything printed in the debug console?

Comment: @PhillipMills Aw crap...yes (that would have been worth checking)... adding now...

Comment: It's possible that the storyboard file's links to the MasterViewController and the DetailViewController have been confused by the import.  I would recommend clicking on each of these elements in the storyboard file, changing the class to something else (e.g. UITableViewController) and then changing them back to the correct ones (i.e. MasterViewController and DetailViewController) and the re-saving the storyboard file